# How to use multiple physical keyboard layouts on Android Oreo 8.1.0 Go Edition phones?

Tags: external-keyboard, android-go

After connecting Bluetooth keyboard to my Android phone, I can't add more than one physical keyboard layout. Here is the picture

[image: Physical Keyboard layouts list]

I mean, using the Ctrl + Space shortcut that has multiple physical keyboard layout options, I can't. My Android phone version is 8.1.0 Oreo Go Edition.

I can't even use the Android system keyboard shortcut!
Example: Notification is displayed by pressing search + n. But pressing the shortcut key is not working.
Here is the picture

[image: Android system keyboard shortcuts]

Answer (score 0):

May be irrelevant, but I had the same issue on MIUI 12.0.4.

Seems like **Layout selection** menu is bugged, but there is a workaround. You need to glitch menu to actually select layouts. Try turn on and off rapidly multiple layouts in couple of seconds (two are usually enough, just one is also works, but much rarer), and after leaving this menu and coming back you can see some of them switched.

In my case after ~10 attempts I managed to enable only layouts I need (English and Russian). They still doesn't display them in layout selection though, but now i can switch them with `Cmd(Win)` + `Space`